# Connecting to a remote server using websockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I'd like to connect to an external server which exposes data via websockets (`ws://`). In this arrangement, my server would act as the client to the external server.

The [ActionCable](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) documentation only gives examples where the Rails application exposes websockets to Javascript clients (usually the frontend served by the Rails application itself). It does not appear to show cases where the intent is to open a websocket client in Ruby.

Questions:

1. How can a Rails application instantiate a websocket client for communicating with another server?
2. If Rails does not provided this functionality via `ActionCable`, how might this be done in pure Ruby?
3. A few unmaintained open source projects can be found when searching for a solution to this problem (such as https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails). If `ActionCable` does not support the functionality described, what third party gem, if any, is considered standard?

Comment: I don't know the data format, but had you already considered Nokogiri?

Answer (score 3):

ActionCable does not provide functionality to build server-side client. As you can see in the [repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable) there no any server client in the source code. But ActionCable uses Faye WebSocket. So the connection with gem ['faye-websocket'](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) from the server to Action cable can look like:

```
 EM.run {
   ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new("ws://localhost:3000/cable")
   ws.on :message do |e| puts e.data end
   ws.on :close do |e| puts 'close' end
 }
```

So, that shows react to ping and disconnect. But there shall be some troubles with a connection to the channel. You can try to build WebSocket with Faye and then connect to that from Faye Client.

But there are no reasons to do that. Each server already listens any HTTP-request and trigger some method when that happens. No reasons to listen to something else all time too. Also, ruby can stream anything and that can be taken by the RestClient ease - maybe that is a better solution for you instead of using cross-server WebSocket